# Trying to upload an image to firebase storage but keep getting the error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, image, firebase-storage

Hello i am trying to upload an image to firebase storage but after following all the instructions in firebase offisial site i am trying to figure out this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at uploadFile (gastro.js:72)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gastro.html:57)

```html
<div>
  <label class="upload-group">
    <h1>Upload file</h1>
    <input type="file" class="upload-group" id="file">
  </label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="url[]" id="uploadButton" 
  onclick="uploadFile()">Submit</button>  // second error is here
</div>
```

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var user;
var selectedFile;

function handleFileSelect(event) {
 $(".upload-group").show();
 selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
};


function uploadFile() {
  var filename = selectedFile.name; //first error is here
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/dogImages/' + filename);
  var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

    // Register three observers:
  // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
  // 2. Error observer, called on failure
  // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, function() {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});

}
```

Comment: Cannot read property x of undefined - so this looks like `[undefined]['name']` this means `selectedFile` is undefined and looking at this part of code it was never defined and even not initialized.

Comment: Looking at your edit `var selectedFile;` it's initialized but still not defined. You have to call `handleFileSelect` before `uploadFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are never populating the variable that references the dom element.
You should make sure your function handleFileSelect is called before uploadFile function

```html
<input type="file" onchange="handleFileSelect(this)" id="file">
```

But this is error prone and you will soon have problems with global variables. I suggest you to improve the handleFileSelect to return the dom node reference and use it like that instead of using global variables:

```js
function handleFileSelect() {
    $(".upload-group").show();
    return document.getElementById('file').files[0];
};

function uploadFile() {
  var filename = handleFileSelect().name;
```

Comment: I did it the way you said and i got the following error: firebase.storage is not a function
    at uploadFile

Comment: You probably changed something else. Which approach are you using? I proposed two: one by adding handleFileSelect to the change event the second one. You are suppose to pick only one, not both.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have used the two different functions to do the work , first is fow getting the input i.e `handleFileSelect`  and other is `uploadFile` so i think there is a problem with the scope binding . the varibale is inside the another scope you want to access. 
you just have to initialize the variable first before accessing it .

than in side the upload function get the instance for that file.
You can use you tag `id` directly to access that

```
function uploadFile () {
   var selectedFile = document.getElementById('file');
  ---------- than same as you code ------------------
}
```

Comment: * not initialize but assign / define. `let variable;` is initialized but still undefined.

Comment: I am suggesting to create the variable inside the same upload function and instantiate it with the javascript `document.getElementById`